Underfloor heating system: identifying the valve's thread?
This is a question spawned from Revamping an old underfloor heating system.

I purchased a single HmIP-VDMOT to check if it could be mounted on the valves that are installed on my underfloor heating system. Unfortunately the adapter that is provided, which is allegedly for a M30 x 1,5mm thread, is too large.
Here's the valve's cap interior:

There seems to be the same symbol on each valve, leading me to think it may represent the brand:



Is it possible to identify the valve based on that? Can I use calipers to measure their thread?
Thanks in advance.

I apologize if my wording was confusing. I meant to say "I have calipers and I know how to use them. Can I identify the matching standard thread size based on that?".

If calipers don't work out for determining the thread pitch, you can use a thread pitch gauge: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61NDG9IiFiL.SL1500.jpg

One thing to recognize is that the thread might not be a standard size. Standards exist for convenience and compatibility, but a manufacturer might choose to be non-standard for any reason. Assuming it is a standard size, it should be possible to determine which size using calipers.
The pitch is relatively easy: measure the distance between crests. You may get a more accurate estimate of the pitch by measuring across multiple crests, then dividing the measurement by the number of roots crossed. For example if you measure from the first to the fifth crest 5.0mm, it crosses four roots and so the pitch is 5.0/4=1.25mm.
If you need to take pitch from an inside thread it could be helpful to take a rubbing of the thread, then measure that. A piece of paper rubbed on the inside thread might work, for example.
The diameter is a bit more difficult. You can easily measure the inside diameter of the female-threaded part (this is approximately the "minor" diameter) or the outside of the male-threaded part (approximately the "major" diameter). The "standard" size is more or less the major diameter rounded up a little bit. This can be further complicated by the fact that the outer/male thread sometimes has its crests truncated so that the part is somewhat less than the published major diameter.
It'll be helpful to consult a chart of standard sizes and make a judgement call as to whether your measurement matches a nominal/standard size.

Thank you very much for the very detailed info, I appreciate it!
The fact that the thread might not be a standard size led me to call a local trusted plumber, which I wanted to do in any case for an overall checkup. He's supposed to come next week, fingers crossed there's no need to change the valves!
